# How to execute NodeJS function on page refresh

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote a small NodeJS application from an example. Heres the part of my code.

**server.js:**

```
var app = express();
var helper = require('./helpers.something.js');

helper.calculate(function(result) {
  app.set('something', result);
});

var router = express.Router();
var home = require(./controllers/home.js);

router.get('/', home.index);
```

**home.js**

```
exports.index = (function(req, res) {
  res.locals.calculations = req.app.get('something');
  res.render('home', {
    data: req.app.get('something');
  });
};
```

The problem I am trying to resolve now is that helper.calculate function is called only when server is started instead of being called every time the page is refreshed. Could anyone advice me how can I call helper.calculate every time the page is refreshed if I want to use the result in both home.js and server.js files as I'm quite lost in express.js documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a middleware that will run the function every time that this route is accessed.

You might change this:

```
helper.calculate(function(result) {
  app.set('something', result);
});

var router = express.Router();
var home = require(./controllers/home.js);

router.get('/', home.index);
```

to something like this:

```
var router = express.Router();
var home = require(./controllers/home.js);

const calculate = (req, res, next) => {
  helper.calculate(function(result) {
    app.set('something', result);
  });
  next();
};

router.get('/', calculate, home.index);
```

OR:

```
var router = express.Router();
var home = require(./controllers/home.js);

const calculate = (req, res, next) => {
  helper.calculate(function(result) {
    app.set('something', result);
    next();
  });
};

router.get('/', calculate, home.index);
```

depending on whether or not you want to wait with running the controller until the `helper.calculate()` finishes.

The other option would be to add this to the controller code in home.js but I assume that you don't want to do that because you would use `app.set()` and `app.get()` one after another so I guess you want to separate the act of setting the variable and using it.